# Mercurial Maven Release plugin problems

Tags: maven-2, mercurial, bitbucket, maven-release-plugin

I love using Maven and distributed SCMs like Mercurial (BitBucket).

However as I bring my project to scale and my Hg repository grows, I am finding the Maven Release plugin more and more cumbersome to work with.

The primary problem is that when a `mvn release:prepare` is called Maven doesn't take advantage of the distributed nature of Hg and performs a full clone of the entire repository to put into a temporary directory.

The issue is very well documented by **Fabrizio Giudici** back in 2009
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/fabriziogiudici/archive/2009/10/29/fixing-two-problems-maven-mercurial-hudson

I would have thought Sonatype might have updated the plugin by now, but alas we are still having to download the entire repo prior to releasing.

I was hoping to reach out to the StackOverflow community to see if anyone else was experiencing this problem and whether anybody has come up with novel ways of solving the dreaded full clone upon a maven release.

Comment: How large is your hg repository?

Comment: It's not too big, but I can see problems coming up later on. It is around 50mbs at the moment

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is what I do to avoid the silly multi push to mercurial with maven:

First make sure you use the correct version of the plugin handling the mercurial type of scm via:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

then execute first the prepare goal

```
mvn release:prepare -DautoVersionSubmodules=true -DreleaseVersion=x.x.x -DdevelopmentVersion=y.y.y-SNAPSHOT -DpushChanges=false
```

note the `pushChanges=false` attribute

```
if all ok then
    hg push
    mvn release:perform
else
    mvn release:clean
    and have fun removing the changeset from local hg repo
endif
```

Comment: Hey Farid, nice one... haven't tried it yet but the flag looks promising. The code below... is that supposed to be pseudo code you suggest I execute according to what happens?

Comment: yes it's pseudo, but you could handle it with any scripting tools (dos, shell,...) using the return error code of maven

Comment: hiya, don't forget to accept the answer if it answers the request.

Comment: Is there any reason for fun when removing the local changeset in case of an error? Shouldn't a "hg rollback" suffice?

Comment: in most of the cases yes, a hg rollback would be enought, with maybe some slight manual file deletion.