# Maven - release:prepare without committing

Tags: maven, release

i'm looking to release a stand-alone patch without committing it. when i prepare a release for a version i get the following error:`[ERROR] fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

can i release without committing?

for now, what i'm doing is generate a jar locally and upload it manually as an artifact.

Comment: By the way, I had this very same error when trying to commit (in contrary to  your intentions, I did want to commit and push to the remote git). In my case, the error was caused due to a bug in the plugin (at least, org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0.0), where it tried to cd into a directory out of the local git repo. I have fixed the problem setting plugin version explicitly to a version 2.5.1.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same issue with mercurial. You need to use the `-DpushChanges=false` argument.

See my anwser to a similar question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769537/mercurial-maven-release-plugin-problems/11866312#11866312)

Comment: This still makes the commits without pushing, so you have to reset your local branch to the pre-prepared state. Any way to get around that?

Comment: if you're doing a batch job with git, you could add these commands:
`git reset HEAD~2 --hard && git clean`

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to commit anything to the SCM, I think you should try do to a [**dry run**](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/usage.html#Do_a_Dry_Run) :

> Since the Release Plugin performs a number of operations that change the project, it may be wise to do a dry run before a big release or on a new project. To do this, commit all of your files as if you were about to run a full release and run:
>   `mvn release:prepare -DdryRun=true`

This is a parameter of the release:prepare Mojo : [dryRun](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#dryRun).

Comment: thanks, that's not exactly what i thought i'd find but it's sure as hell close enough :)

Comment: Can you do a `release:perform` after this to publish without committing any changes?

Comment: The doc (http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#dryRun) says : _Dry run: don't checkout anything from the scm repository, or modify the checkout. The goals (by default at least deploy) will not be executed._

Comment: And _the goals_ make reference to http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#goals. So I guess there will be nothing deployed (distributed) on a repository.

Comment: This doesn't work if your requirement is that it also pushes to the artifact repository.